# PHP static scope redeclare

Tags: php

I got this example when working with static scope in PHP function:

```
function testStatic() {
static $a;
echo "here is a first time: ".$a."<br />";
$a = 23;
static $a = 100;
echo "here is a second time: ".$a."<br />";
}
```

when I run this function like this

```
teststatic(); echo "<hr />";
teststatic();
```

It output result below:

here is a: 100
here is a: 23

---

here is a: 23
here is a: 23

**But I expect it to be the following:**
here is a: null
here is a: 100

---

here is a: 100
here is a: 100
I have been thinking hours try to explain why I received the result above but really failed.
Could you tell me why we have  the result above? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like explicit definitions of `static` variables are being recognized first (like functions are).

Comment: I've never seen statics defined within a function like this. Usually they are defined within a class context, then referenced inside member methods or outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to believe that the output you indicate is really the output of that code. Yet the problem is clear here:

A `static` variable is bound to a function or class and declared via the `static` keyword. You are re-declaring `$a`; this should (I guess) raise a warning.

As `static` properties are part of the function's or class' definition, (apparently) the last occurrence of  it will be "attached" to the function/class in question.

Only the first time the function is called `$a` is assigned the value of `23`. After the first `echo` statement.

This is a 2-step process, first the parser will read the function's definition, including `static` properties. After that the code will run, and the properties are mutated.